# Measuring peak disk use of a process

Tags: linux, bash, io, diskspace, data-profiling

I am trying to benchmark a tool I'm developing in terms of time, memory, and disk use. I know `/usr/bin/time` gives me basically what I want for the first two, but for disk use I came to the conclusion I would have to roll my own bash script that periodically extracts the 'bytes written' contents from `/proc/<my_pid>/io`. Based on this [script](https://github.com/GATB/gatb-minia-pipeline/blob/master/tools/memused), here's what I came up with:

```
"$@" &
pid=$!
status=$(ps -o rss -o vsz -o pid | grep $pid)
maxdisk=0
while [ "${#status}" -gt "0" ];
do
    sleep 0.05
    delta=false
    disk=$(cat /proc/$pid/io | grep -P '^write_bytes:' | awk '{print $2}')
    disk=$(disk/1024)
    if [ "0$disk" -gt "0$maxdisk" ] 2>/dev/null; then
        maxdisk=$disk
        delta=true
    fi
    if $delta; then
        echo disk: $disk
    fi
    status=$(ps -o rss -o vsz -o pid | grep $pid)
done
wait $pid
ret=$?
echo "maximal disk used: $maxdisk KB"
```

Unfortunately, I am running into two problems:

- The first is that I am piping the output of this script along with that of the tool I would like to benchmark to a file, and it seems occasionally these streams interfere, leading me to see 0 or too low disk use reported at the bottom of this file.
- The second problem is that I don't know what to do about processes that delete temporary files as part of their process. In this case I think the fair benchmark would be to record the maximum *net* disk use (i.e., the peak in bytes written - bytes erased), but I don't know where the second part of this difference can be found.

How can I resolve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to have a look at [`filetop`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/filetop_example.txt) from [BCC - Tools for BPF-based Linux IO analysis, networking, monitoring, and more](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc):

> tools/filetop: File reads and writes by filename and process. Top for files.
>
> This script works by tracing the `vfs_read()` and `vfs_write()` functions using kernel dynamic tracing, which instruments explicit read and write calls. If files are read or written using another means (eg, via `mmap()`), then they will not be visible using this tool.

Brendan Gregg gives good talks and demos about [Linux Performance Tools,](https://youtu.be/FJW8nGV4jxY?list=PLhhdIMVi0o5RNrf8E2dUijvGpqKLB9TCR)  they are quite instructive.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found this similar question: [How do I measure net used disk space change due to activity by a given process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900758/how-do-i-measure-net-used-disk-space-change-due-to-activity-by-a-given-process-i?rq=1).

Based on the answers there, this seams to be a thorny problem due to the difficulty in tracking all the different types of changes that may be initiated by a given process.

Dtrace is also mentioned there, but as I understand it, it is proprietary to Sun (or I guess Oracle now?) and thus available by only on Solaris by default. Eventually I found this Github [repo](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux), aiming to close that gap for Linux users.

Comment: You may like to watch [Give me 15 minutes and I'll change your view of Linux tracing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsMs3n8CB6g).

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it differently, not worry at all about deleted files, by using multiple timestamps in your records, giving you:

- Disk writes delta over time. eg 8 GB/day. Doesn't matter if all of it to /tmp. Each time it is run a new average saved to disc, with a counter, to keep a rolling average. So if each hour you errant process does 2 GB, then 1 GB, then 0 GB, each hour, thats 1 GB/hour (for the time period)
- For each snapshot, you pick the highest, record that, in this case 2 GB for the first hour of operation. If you run the script each hour and it's always 0 GB, it will report 2 GB in the first hour. Then if in the wee smalls it kicks up and puts down 5 GB, you "peak" will show that at 3am say, with average of 333 MB/hour.